# Are you allowed to bake bread in two different ovens?

Tags: agricola

If I build both the clay oven and the stone oven, and I play a bake bread action, am I allowed to cook two grain in my clay oven, and one clay in my stone oven, for a total of thirteen food?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use as many ovens as you want each time you take the bake bread action.

Unfortunately the rulebook itself is not completely clear on this point. But multiple answers [on bgg](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/369035/bakin-bread-how-much) agree.